# Need help configuring 301 permanent redirect in Apache for non www

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to configure my Apache 2.2 version to use a 301 permanent redirect when someone types my url without the www.  I want to configure this in the httpd.conf and not using .htaccess if possible.  I have tried using Redirect permanent but the first variable has to be a directory and not a url.  Any ideas how to configure boom.com requests to be redirected to www.boom.com using a 301 redirect in Apache?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
# Canonical hostnames
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.boom\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !=""
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.boom.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all request which don't match www.boom.com to www.boom.com, with the same query path. (For example, boom.com/foo?foo=bar will be redirect to www.boom.com/foo?foo=bar).

Comment: We already have a whole set of RewriteCond lines.  I would prefer to not mess with these.  Is this the only option?

Comment: You could put the extra RewriteCond entries in a VirtualHost block to isolate them from the rest?

Answer (score 1):

If you have named virtual hosts you could put the extra RewriteCond entries @tux21b gave inside to isolate them. Also if you have mod_alias you could try this which should do the same thing:

```
<VirtualHost boom.com:80>
    RedirectMatch permanent /.* http://www.boom.com$0
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm sure someone will comment if there's a reason to use one over the other.